# Contribution in construction of mosque

Tags: hadith, prophets, masjid

Assalam u alaykum, can we contribute in construction of mosque if yes then what will be the reward? As far as I know Prophet Mohammed (pbuh) said whoever construct the mosque, Allah will build the palace for him in Jannah. But how about if someone is contributing a little money in construction of mosque what reward he will gets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

allah rewards as per niyah(intention) not on the basis of amount

if you contribute in building mosque it will be sawab -e -jariya(reward even after your death )

> Narrated Abu Hurairah [رضی اللّٰہُ عنہ]: "The Messenger of Allah [صلی
>   اللہ علیہ وسلم] said: "The good deeds that will reach a believer after
>   his death are: knowledge which he learned and then spread; a righteous
>   son whom he leaves behind; a copy of the Qur'an that he leaves as a
>   legacy; a mosque that he built; a house that he built for wayfarers; a
>   canal that he dug; or charity that he gave during his lifetime when he
>   was in good health. These deeds will reach him after his death."
>   [Ibn Majah: 224]